# show datepicker multi month in multiple rows

Tags: c#, jquery, datepicker

if i put this code to show [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 9,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
</script>
```

it shows 9 months all in the same row.  Is there anyway to show a grid where i have 3 rows of 3 months each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the [`numberOfMonths` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-numberOfMonths) as an array instead to do what you want, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: [3, 3],
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
</script>
```